# Unattended upgrades not running under Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, debian, apt, ubuntu-14.04, unattended

I have a bunch of servers running Ubuntu 14.04.

They all have the unattended-upgrades package installed.

I've created a file called: /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/local-50-unattended

And I've added the file to each server.

The contents of the file are as follows:

```
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";
APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "1";
APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval "7";
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1";

// List of packages to not update (regexp are supported)
Unattended-Upgrade::Package-Blacklist {
    "^postgresql-";
    "^redis-";
};
```

I like the idea of the configuration being in a new standalone file, and I'd hope this would work.

But it doesn't.  None of the security updates seem to be getting installed.

What did I do wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

Ubuntu/Debian won't install older security updates that existed before you setup your system for automated updates.

Everything above works perfectly, assuming that at the time you set it up your system is already up to date.